# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't slide the images

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am was trying to use the bootsrap to create a carousel on the the webpage. I sopied the code and inserted images, but the animation isn't hapenning. There would be only one picture and it would not move. I might be missing something very basic. Thank you.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="/_assets/carpic1.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="pic1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="_assets/carpic2.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="pic2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/_assets/carpic3.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="pic3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

I have tried to see if I am missing something or whether I copied the full code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you loading in the bootstrap js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Add these Libraries if you are using Bootstrap 5

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-heAjqF+bCxXpCWLa6Zhcp4fu20XoNIA98ecBC1YkdXhszjoejr5y9Q77hIrv8R9i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and also these

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-qKXV1j0HvMUeCBQ+QVp7JcfGl760yU08IQ+GpUo5hlbpg51QRiuqHAJz8+BrxE/N" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```